# What is 3-force in special relativity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, forces, classical-mechanics, vectors

We define 4-force as one which satisfies: $\mathbf{f}=m \mathbf{a}$ where $\mathbf{a}=\frac{d \mathbf{u}}{d \tau}$.

The quantities in bold face are 4-vectors.

*Hartle pg 88* defines a 3-force as:

$\frac{d \vec{p}}{d t} \equiv \vec{F}$

Where $\vec{p}=\frac{m \vec{V}}{\sqrt{1-\vec{V}^2}}$ Is the three momentum.

Is this 3-force what we measure? I.e  The force that we used in Newtonian mechanics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. In the limit of $v \ll c$ we get the usual Newtonian expression for the momentum:

$$ p = mv $$

and differentiating this wrt coordinate time $t$ gives us the force we measure in our coordinate system.

Comment: So the three force is the same in Newtonian mechanics and in relativistic dynamics.

Comment: @Kashmiri yes, but note that as the speeds approach $c$ you need to modify the definitions of the momentum to $p = \gamma mv$ otherwise Newton's second law won't be obeyed. And note also that anything differentiated wrt coordinate time is going to be frame dependent and therefore not a fundamental property.

Comment: Thanks. To use Newton's second law in relativistic limits modify velocity by $\gamma$ , the 3 force remains unchanged.